# Postgresql show specific value first, order by different criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

In this small exercise I need to show people from "Zoetermeer" first and 
order them by name, people with the same name need to be ordered by "bondsnr" (this is a unique number),
people with a place other than "Zoetermeer" need to be sorted only by "bondsnr".

```
select spelersnr, naam, plaats, bondsnr
from spelers
where bondsnr is not null
order by case when plaats = 'Zoetermeer' then 1
          else 2 end,
          bondsnr
```

This is what I have now but it's not correct and I can't seem to find the solution. 
Sorting the people from "Zoetermeer" first works but I don't know how I can sort the people with the same name by their number

EDIT

```
spelersnr   naam       plaats      bondsnr    
    27     Cools      Zoetermeer    2513
   104   Moerman      Zoetermeer    7060
    44   Bakker, de     Rijswijk    1124
   112   Baalen, van   Rotterdam    1319
    83  Hofland         Den Haag    1608
     2  Elfring         Den Haag    2411
     8  Niewenburg      Rijswijk    2983
    57  Bohemen, van    Den Haag    6409
   100  Permentier      Den Haag    6524
     6  Permentier      Den Haag    8467
```

This is how it should be.
My answer shows the same result but it's not correct.
I think because I don't order by name if they live at the same place

Comment: Show us some sample result, ordered the way you want it. (As well formatted text.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort query not only by individual columns, but also by [records](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).
So if I understand your requirement correctly:

```
select spelersnr, naam, plaats, bondsnr
from spelers
where bondsnr is not null
order by
  case
    when plaats = 'Zoetermeer' then
      (1,naam,bondsnr)
    else
      (2,null::text,bondsnr)
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

You can cast a bool to an int and then order by your preferred criteria.

Example:

```
with a (a, b, c) as (values (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 2))
select * from a order by (a.a = 2)::int desc, b desc;
 a | b | c
---+---+---
 2 | 3 | 2
 2 | 1 | 3
 1 | 3 | 2
 1 | 2 | 3
(4 rows)

db_example=# with a (a, b, c) as (values (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 2))
db_example-# select * from a order by (a.a = 2)::int desc, b asc;                                                  
  a | b | c                                                                                                              
 ---+---+---                                                                                                             
  2 | 1 | 3                                                                                                               
  2 | 3 | 2                                                                                                               
  1 | 2 | 3                                                                                                               
  1 | 3 | 2                                                                                                              
(4 rows)
```

for booleans, true becomes 1 and false becomes 0

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to redo a bit: `SELECT a.a=2 AS a2 FROM a ORDER BY a2 `. This way I was able to implement it in SQLAlchemy. I left out the `::int` as boolean can also be ordered.